# How to define a criterion for duplicate instances of an object in Java?

Tags: java, duplicates, equals

I have a class with some primary fields which are mandatory and required by all of its constructors, and then other secondary fields that can be defaulted to an empty value if they don't get initialized. The combination of the primary fields is what identifies each instance of the class as a unique and distinct object, so that **another instance with the same primary fields may be considered a duplicate even if it has different secondary fields**.

The check for duplicate instances is needed for storing the objects in a list-like structure that doesn't allow for duplicates, and it's performed by overriding `equals()` (which, for example, is used by `ArrayList.contains()`) to make it look only at the primary fields while completely ignoring all the secondary ones.

Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Yes, this is a main reason to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` (so that their contract is maintained)

Comment: "The combination of the primary fields is what identifies each instance of the class as a unique and distinct object" Then yes, only check the primary fields in `equals` (*and `hashCode`*).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use all your primary variables to construct a hashcode in hashCode().
Then either use if conditions or hashcode in your equals().